# How to change restangular method on put

Tags: restangular

```
 cars.one('loadEspecial').one('10').get().then(function(data){                        
       $scope.car = data;                        
 });

$scope.save = function(car){
    car.put().then(function(data){ 
        if (data.ok == false) { 
           alert('ok');
        } else {
           alert('not ook');
        } 

    });                
};
```

I need to send
http://localhost:8086/Server/car/loadEspecial/10

and it´s sending
http://localhost:8086/Server/car/loadEspecial/10/10

the other problem is the interceptor
I have to put 10, and the correctly is car, how can I change it ?

```
        Restangular.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element,operation,what,url,headers,query) {
            if (operation == 'put') {       
                switch (what) {
                    case '10':
                        return { element: {car : element} };
                        break;

                    default :
                        return;
                        break;
                }                            
            }                    
});
```